# Getting a bad request response from an api call that is supposed to return a link to be used for iframe src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, iframe, axios

I am trying to do a GET method so that I can get back the link to be used in the src attribute of the iframe. So what I did was the following:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_API_ROOT } from '../../apiConfig';

async function getJobView() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: `${BASE_API_ROOT}/level2`
  };

  return axios(options);
}

export { getJobView };
```

So I tried to embed the iframe into a popup modal. So what I did was import that api function and use it in my component like below:

```
  modalContent = () => {
    const { classes, history } = this.props;

    const srcUrl = getJobView().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err.message));
    console.log(srcUrl);
    const renderGetJobView = () => {
      return <iframe src={srcUrl} style={{ width: '800px', height: '800px' }}></iframe>
    }
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.modalPaper}>
        {renderGetJobView()}
      </Paper>
    );
  };
```

In the console I see this:
[image]

Any idea about this?

Comment: This means, you're getting 404 from your response. Check if there is anything wrong in your server.

Comment: 404 is a "not found" error, which means that your requested api url does not exist. Check your api endpoints and see if your url '${BASE_API_ROOT}/level2' exists.  The error msg seems structured so there may be a way to trace the error in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

The requested resource was not found.

`404` status code means `resource not found`. Check your `server` side your calling correct API's `URL`.

Here you can check status code of API's [api_response_codes](https://documentation.commvault.com/11.24/essential/45599_rest_api_response_codes_and_statuses.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather format your code in more readable way and try to find out where it break.

**axios.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_API_ROOT } from '../../apiConfig';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_API_ROOT,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
})

export const getJobView = async () => {
    return axiosInstance.get("/level2")
}
```

**component.js**

```js
const modalContent = () => {
    const { classes, history } = this.props;
    const [srcUrl, setSrcUrl] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        const getJobViewData = async () => {
            try {
                const getJobViewResponse = await getJobView()
                setSrcUrl(getJobViewResponse.data)
            } catch (error) {
                setSrcUrl("")
            }
        }
        getJobViewData()
    }, [])
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.modalPaper}>
            {srcUrl !== ""
                ? <iframe src={srcUrl} style={{ width: '800px', height: '800px' }}></iframe>
                : null
            }
        </Paper>
    );
};
```

Now, It's easy to find out where the code breaks, either in Api endpoint or somewhere else.